# Back up & Restore Tenants in a Multi Tenant SharePoint 2013 environment

Tags: sharepoint-server, backup, restore, multi-tenancy

I have a SharePoint 2013 environment with Multi-Tenancy configured. I have various tenants provisioned in the environment. Is it possible to backup and restore a tenant from one environment to another. If so, please provide the steps.

PS: I know we can backup a single site collection using PowerShell, but a tenant normally has a group of site collections grouped with a subscription. Hence I am raising this. Also, I know there is a Content DB backup approach. But what about the other aspects, which are required to be kept in mind while doing this, like Service Applications, Permissions, Users, Custom Code, SharePoint version and so on. Please provide your inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Check this similar thread thread - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a665b5a-b2ba-4308-a3a3-f6c184d71187/back-up-restore-tenants-in-a-multi-tenant-sharepoint-2013-environment?forum=sharepointadmin

Comment: Hello Ven! It will be great if you can update this question from the feedback on the question posted by you on Technet forum as pointed out by David! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting me how to post, I'll keep this in my mind.